# With a Full-Frame Camera, will a Full-Frame Fisheye Lens produce a Circular Image?

Tags: canon, full-frame, fisheye

I am looking to buy my first full-frame camera, but I want some clarity on this one point.

I have the Canon 8-15 mm full-frame fisheye lens, it works great on my non-full-frame Canon DSLR.  In the most open position, the lens will produce an image on my camera which has rounded corners and some cropping of the circular image in the center.  With the full-frame camera, should I expect to see the entire circular image?  If not, what do I need to do in order to get the entire circular image in frame?

Thank you

Comment: If your task is to have circular image with black surrounding you may always shield it in post even if you are out of luck.

Answer (score 4):

The link below reviews a Canon 8-15mm lens.  It shows sample images from various focal lengths on both full frame and cropped sensors.  According to these images, yes indeed will see the full circle when shooting at 8mm on a full frame camera.

http://www.lenstip.com/311.1-Lens_review-Canon_EF_8-15_mm_f_4_L_Fisheye_USM_Introduction.html

Here is the specific image:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

> With the full-frame camera, should I expect to see the entire circular image?

It depends on what focal length you've set the lens to. The EF 8-15mm f/4L USM fisheye is unique in being circular at the wide end (at least on full frame it is), and diagonal at the "tele" end.  Where you are in the zoom range determines how much of the frame is covered by the lens's image circle.

Most fisheyes are prime lenses, and are either circular (fit the entire image circle in the frame) or diagonal (fit the entire frame inside the image circle). The typical focal length for a full frame circular is 8mm, and for a diagonal is 15mm. On APS-C, the only circular I know of is the [Sigma 4.5mm](https://www.sigmaphoto.com/45mm-f28-ex-dc-hsm-circular-fisheye), and most APS-C 8mm lenses are diagonal.

> If not, what do I need to do in order to get the entire circular image in frame?

You need to have the 8-15L's zoom set to 8mm.

See also: the [8-15L review on the-digital-picture.com](http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Canon-EF-8-15mm-f-4-L-USM-Fisheye-Lens-Review.aspx), it has a graphic example, of what the lens will look like on full frame at different focal length settings, where you can mouse over the zoom setting, and see the resultant frame.

Answer (score 0):

A lens projects the image that it projects.  Meaning, the body does not affect what is projected, but sensor size does of course show more or less of it (full frame vs cropped frame).  The same lens on a full frame body will show a near half again wider view of that lens image, so yes, you would see greatly more rounded corners.  Including full circle, but it will depend on focal length used.

See samples at https://shop.usa.canon.com/shop/en/catalog/ef-8-15mm-f-4l-fisheye-usm